# Pause processes in remote host and resume execution in another remote host

Tags: linux, shell, ssh

Given addresses of 2 remote machines[say src and dest], using a single shell script how to:
 1. get the state of running processes in "src" 
 2. stop all the processes in "src"
 3. exit out of "src"
 4. ssh into "dest"
 5. resume the state of executing processes captured in step 1 in "dest"

Assumption:"src" is already logged in using ssh and processes are running in it.

Thanks in advance,
Saeya

Answer (score 2):

What you are describing is called 'checkpointing and restarting', or 'process migration'. On easy-to-use tool that allows to do that is [DMTCP](http://dmtcp.sourceforge.net/). Another one, less easy to use, but able to restore more complex states, is [BLCR](http://crd.lbl.gov/groups-depts/ftg/projects/current-projects/BLCR). Finally, if you have a recent kernel on both src and dest, [Criu](http://criu.org/Main_Page) is the most promising, but less mature than the other two.